# Failed to generate code. Exception of type 'System.Data.Design.InternalException' was thrown, however using web.config for connection

Tags: c#, dataset

I have create a web app, but when I push it live using IIS, I get the following error

> Failed to generate code. Exception of type 'System.Data.Design.InternalException' was thrown.

Line 1:
 `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>`

Line 2: 
    `<xs:schema id="test" targetNamespace="test.xsd" xmlns:mstns="http://tempuri.org/test.xsd" xmlns="http://tempuri.org/test.xsd" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" xmlns:msprop="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msprop" attributeFormDefault="qualified" elementFormDefault="qualified">`

Line 3: `<xs:annotation>`

I have read online that it is the connection, however when I created the dataset, I used my web.config connection string as the reference point.
However when I check the XSD it is pointing to my web.config.

Comment: Have you checked the `InternalException`? ;)

Comment: how do i check that on a live server deploy

Comment: You have no log files?

Comment: Nop - how do i turn them on?